# Resolving Resolution Issues with Multiple Monitors on Laptop

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

I have been struggling for the past few hours to set up my Dell Alienware m15 laptop with two monitors: Philips 275E1S and ASUS TUF Gaming VG27AQ1A. Unfortunately, I'm encountering a problem where not all resolutions are displayed in the resolution list for the Philips 275E1S. Currently, Windows only shows options for 1280x720, 1024x768, and 800x600.

Here are the steps I have taken so far to address the issue:

1- Changing the resolution using the Intel Graphics Command Center: I only see one option in this app, which is "Open System Settings" to change the resolution. However, it does indicate that the monitor supports higher resolutions like 2560 x 1440.

2- Updating drivers.

3- Adding custom modes using Custom Resolution Utility (CRU): Unfortunately, this method doesn't work as it doesn't add any new modes to the Windows Modes list.

4- Windows troubleshooting.

5- Trying different HDMI cables.

6- NVIDIA Control Panel

Interestingly, when I connect the Philips monitor alone, without the Asus monitor, it displays all available resolutions and works perfectly fine. I have also used two old monitors without any issues. Furthermore, both monitors work flawlessly without any issues on my main PC.

One additional piece of information is that the Intel® Driver & Support Assistant shows two graphics in my system: the NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU with a resolution of 1280 x 720, and the Intel® Iris® Xe Graphics with a resolution of 2560 x 1440.

So does anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: Monitors may sometimes also need drivers, the Philips driver may be [here](https://www.philips.co.uk/c-p/275E1S_01/lcd-monitor/support).